# Trying to get all lines from csv file where column 8 equal a value using awk, but it prints all lines and matching lines twice

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file and I want to get a subset of the lines where column 8 is equal to a specific value. I'm doing this:

```
awk 'FS=","; $8 == 0' infile.csv
```

The output of this command is that it prints every line in the file at least once, but the lines where the 8th column is 0, it will print twice. Why is it doing this? How do I get it to just print the matching lines once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two blocks `FS=","` and  `$8 == 0`. The implied action when the condition is satisfied is `{print}`.  The first assignment returned value is non false, therefore it prints the record.  Whereas the second condition is only true when it's satisfied, that's why you see that record printed twice.

If you don't want the assignment to be used as a condition wrap with curly braces.

```
$ awk '{FS=","} $8==0{print}'
```

However, setting `FS` again and again for each record is unnecessary

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $8==0'
```

will do the same.  However the easiest will be using the `-F`

```
$ awk -F, '$8==0'
```

Comment: Setting FS again and again for each record is worse than unnecessary, it doesn't work since the first input line will have been split into fields before FS is set to `,` the first time so that first line will be split on spaces instead of `,`s.